# Jmeter Non GUI mode timestamp date format

Tags: jmeter, date-format, epoch

I am using JMeter in Non-GUI mode and able to generate the .csv and .jtl files but the timestamp in the results file is in Epoch format and I want it to be in date (yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss) format.

I did go to the /bin/user.properties file and made the necessary changes, but still the report looks same as before and has the timestamp in epoch format. This is what my user.properties looks like

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes = true
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time = true
# the timestamp format must include the time and should include the date.
# For example the default, which is milliseconds since the epoch: 
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
# Or the following would also be suitable
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Did you restart JMeter after that? Did you use `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` or `ddmmyyyy` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Naveen All this is done in Non-GUI mode and so there is no questions on restarting the JMeter, Right? And for the date format, I have edited the question to reflect the same format in both the places.

Comment: yeah! my bad. no need of restarting it in Non-GUI mode. I tried with your settings and it is working for me. could you please share the command that you ran and JMeter version.

Comment: @Naveen This is the command i used to run the JMeter test  

jmeter -n -t "PATH TO JMX" -l "OutputFile.csv" and i am using apache-jmeter-3.1

Comment: I don't see any wrong-doing here. because I tried with same version and similar command. working fine for me. better confirm the issue by running in GUI mode once.

Comment: @Naveen can you confirm which file you have made the changes in? is it user.properties or jmeter.properties?

Comment: it is `user.properties` file. properties defined here, will override those in `jmeter.properties`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check your *user.properties* file, maybe you have a duplicate property somewhere and JMeter picks the one it finds first. Another assumption: try removing starting (and ending, if any) whitespace, maybe the property cannot be parsed as a valid [SimpleDateFormat pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries

As a workaround you can override the timestamp format via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" -n -t example.jmx -l example.csv
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter property override timestamp]

More information on working with JMeter Properties: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It spits out the date as required.  I have a follow up question here, which date format should I use to have the timestamp in this format "2016-12-29T20:01:14.108Z"?

Comment: nvm. i found out the data format, it is : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'